# Exception in SmirnovTest

Tags: java, kolmogorov-smirnov

For the given data set and code, SmirnovTest shows the given exception-

data1[30]=
{190.0, 173.33, 174.67, 174.0, 177.33, 171.33, 166.0, 184.0, 176.67, 179.33, 163.33, 152.0, 175.33, 147.33, 169.33, 183.33, 196.0, 170.0, 176.0, 142.0, 168.0, 173.33, 179.33, 154.67, 160.67, 175.33, 158.0, 159.33, 158.0, 171.33 };

data2[20]=
{46.04, 23.8, 23.29, 15.35, 52.62, 59.46, 42.02, 50.31, 32.07, 16.87, 16.72, 62.91, 48.74, 52.87, 57.32, 15.61, 59.3, 45.62, 64.22, 61.42};

SmirnovTest test=new SmirnovTest(data1, data2);

test.getSP();

test.getTestStatistic();

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid SP -3.126388037344441E-13**

Is there any problem in data set?

Comment: What library are you using? What is SP in this context?

Comment: I used the jsc(java statistical class) library. The test is ok for some other data sets but it shows error for this and some other data sets.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that [`getSP()`](http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/jsc/independentsamples/SmirnovTest.html#getSP()) returns the significance probability (also known as the p-value) for the test, but it is somehow calculated as a negative number. I should probably read up on the K-S test first (and maybe disassemble JSC for a bit), but this smells very much like a bug in JSC.

Comment: You should check the value of test.getSP() before trying to get the test statistic. Your data sets are so wildly not from the same distribution that the SP value was negative (probably due to roundoff and/or truncation), and you should abandon trying to get test statistics when there is essentially a zero probability of a fit..

Comment: @FredK I have to say that it's *incredibly* disappointing that that flow (if `getSP()` is negative, then don't call `getTestStatistic()`) is not specified in the API.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Mat Lab calculate the p-value 0 for the same data and in the case of jsc if the p-value is 0 or negative(?) it shows this type of exception.